# How can I activate ALL jQuery Modal Boxes (without knowing their invididual IDs ahead of time)?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-dialog

I am having an issue with a custom AJAX library that works like this:

**Example Custom AJAX**

```
<input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Save"
    onclick="process_form(
        'save_form',            //form ID
        'index.php?c=save',     //AJAX call to server with form data
        'index.php?c=homepage', //AJAX call to redirect on Success
        'home_page_div',        //DIV that will accept above redirect response
        'POST'                  //method to use for form data
    );" />

<!--
This is how custom AJAX activates a function after it is done 
and also where I could activate an INDIVIDUAL box,
but I don't know know them ahead of time
-->
<img src="icons/blank.png" onload="validate_data()" />
```

**Problem**

It does not activate jQuery Modal boxes.  I have noted that when I use jQuery's own AJAX calls, Modal boxes are activated.  How is a mystery to me.  It seems that jQuery activates all JS code inside response that is pulled into a DIV.  However in my case my custom AJAX does not activate JS nor modal boxes.

**Possible Solution**

in my `onload` box I can specify which modal box to activate.  But I don't know the modal boxes IDs ahead of time.

**Possible Solution 2**

Rewrite AJAX calls using jQuery (remove custom AJAX calls).
Problem:  there dozens of places that use custom ajax, making such a rewrite impractical.  I did do the rewrite in some places, but a lot of functionality is based around custom ajax calls and I rather fine a different solution.
**Question**

How do I activate ALL jQuery Modal Boxes?

For example, jQuery has this for tabs:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
</script>
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dialog1").dialog();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<div id="dialog1" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>Dialog 1 has been activated.</p>
</div>

<div id="dialog2" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>Dialog 2 is NOT activated :(</p>
</div>

<div id="dialog3" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>Dialog 3 is NOT activated :(</p>
</div>
```

**BONUS**

Why does jQuery activate all JS/jQuery that is contained inside a response that is pulled via AJAX into a DIV, while some other methods don't.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of selecting by ID, you should select by class. You would need to add the same class to each of the dialog divs like this

```
<div id="dialog1" class="modalDialog" title="Basic dialog"> 
  <p>Dialog 1 has been activated.</p>
</div>

<div id="dialog2" class="modalDialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>Dialog 2 has been activated.</p>
</div>

<div id="dialog3" class="modalDialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>Dialog 3 has been activated.</p>
</div>
```

Then you can open all your dialogs like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".modalDialog").dialog();
});
```

You can see it in action in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ayqrxesu/).

Answer (score 0):

turns out there were other issues, such as .. other JS/jQuery on my page that was being loaded into a DIV upon pressing `<submit>` button.

So enabling just jQuery Boxes did not help.  There were more JS code to enable.

Essentially my problem was "JS code found in response object and placed into a DIV not activating".  My custom AJAX library did not help with that.

Replacing it with jQuery mechanisms added the **MAGIC** that executed *ALL my JS* that was inside the content of AJAX response.

Comment: With regards to your Bonus question, without looking at your code, I have no idea. Glad replacing it with jQuery worked for you. If you can, you should change over from using the old style `onclick` events to jQuery's `$.click()` events. Moving all the JS code to a separate .js file will be much easier to debug and keep it organized.